# How to show widget when alarm fired in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to show widget from callback but it seem context not found and giving this error:

E/flutter (22300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter (22300): Receiver: null
E/flutter (22300): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType()

```
    static BuildContext _context;


    static Future<void> callback() async {
    print('Alarm fired!');

    // Get the previous cached count and increment it.
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey);

    Navigator.push(
      _context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AlarmScreen(
          id: currentCount,
        ),
      ),
    );
    await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);

    // This will be null if we're running in the background.
    uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(isolateName);
    uiSendPort?.send(null);
  }
  

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        setState(() {
          _context = context;
        });
```